# Error al publicar web service en visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, webservice

Soy novato en programación y tengo un error al momento de tratar de publicar mi web service en visual studio 2017, me sale un mensaje con el siguiente error:
[image: Mensaje de error]

Al accerder al archivo .tmp que muestra el mensaje me muestra lo siguiente:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.
   en Microsoft.VisualStudio.ApplicationCapabilities.Publish.Provider.DefaultPublishTabProvider.InitializeProvider(IVsHierarchy hierarchy)
   en Microsoft.VisualStudio.ApplicationCapabilities.Publish.Provider.DefaultPublishTabProvider.CreateViewAsync(IVsHierarchy project, IAsyncServiceProvider serviceProvider, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   en Microsoft.VisualStudio.ApplicationCapabilities.Publish.Provider.ManagedPublishProvider.<CreateViewAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
```

No sé que problema lo este ocasionando.

Espero su respuesta. Muchas gracias

Comment: si en lugar de publicar, simplemente compilas lo hace sin errores? si ejecutas desde el VS inicia la pagina web y puedes navegarla?

Comment: No hay error alguno al momento de compilarlo. El problema persiste.